# Получить название приложения Steam с помощью его ID

Tags: c++, steam

Как получить название приложения Steam, если известно ID приложения (используя SteamAPI) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете get запрос через угодную вам http библиотеку по адресу
`store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=<id>`

Парсите json и достаете оттуда имя игры, там в иерархии есть.

Алсо, есть специальная библиотека для работы со Steam API

https://habr.com/ru/post/157999/